# Can .net dynamic load c++/cli dll from memory?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a c++/cli dll which depends on a native dll. By embedding the native dll into cli dll using memory module im able to pack them into one mixed dll.
I wonder if it's possible to embed this mixed dll into .net exe and load from memory(without extracting files to disk).
I've tried Ilmerge and System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(byte[]...) and it doesnt work.

so what i do now is extract the dll before and function get called then delete it after program finished which i dont want.

Comment: It is not possible to load a mixed-mode assembly from memory. The same goes for any native dll. Try compiling as pure IL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixed-mode dll has dependencies on native dlls and can't be loaded from memory because of a limitation of the Windows image loader. I've already seen some C++ code that loads a dll from memory but I doubt you want to go this way. It basically reimplemented the loader.

But if you want to distribute your exe as a single file, I can advise you to use [LibZ](https://libz.codeplex.com/). With this tool, you can embed mixed-mode dlls as resources to your C# assembly. When your C# module is loaded, it will dump the mixed-mode assembly to a temp folder and load it transparently. You can even embed two versions of the mixed-mode dll, one for each platform: x86 or x64.